# Spring integration error:- org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel while connecting to MQ

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-integration, message-queue, spring-jms

I am trying to use Spring integration to connect to JMS client , but i am getting :-

[WARN ] 2018-08-22 10:57:20.378 [DispatchThread: [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[connectionId=414D514353414D5030303144202020206CF77A5B9E4A5E21]]] SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
**org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'app-name:local:9010.inputChannel'**.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage

and below is my spring integration configuration class

Any idea why i am getting this exception .

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the message says.

> Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'app-name:local:9010.inputChannel'.

You have no subscriber on this bean

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
public void handle(String in) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "transformed")
public String handle(String in) {
    retur in.toUpperCase();
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "transformed")
public void handle(String in) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you understand Spring Integration? It depends on what you want to do with the message. Typically, you will have a `@ServiceActivator` POJO method to handle the message.

Comment: I added an example to my answer; see [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).